# Help me with punctuation, please!

Tags: grammar, punctuation

How should one insert the punctuation in the text below:

> We were informed a complete set of dishes consists of these items cups
>   saucers and plates bowls are not included.

Comment: Homework and proofreading questions are off topic here. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour)
 and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help)
 for a better understanding of how this site operates.

Comment: @medica - I need some EL&U advice. Can you assist?

Answer (score 2):

In spite of obvious close-vote candidacy, I'll answer here because there's an interesting complication. This is that 'inform' can be used as a quotative verb as well as a strict reporting verb.

> We were informed: 'A complete set of dishes consists of these items –
>   cups, saucers and plates; bowls are not included.'

[I had to choose where I preferred the colon; two would look messy.]

In Britain, I'd say that *inform* used in a report structure is rarely if ever used without the complementiser *that*. But I'll assume that's not the case in the US. Hence both the following

> We were informed [that] a complete set of dishes consists of these
>   items: cups, saucers, and plates; bowls are not included.

would be acceptable.

Comment: In the US it's more normal to hear the [that] but we get it without, too.

Comment: I think your second is best of all.

Comment: I prefer your first example :-). The brackets indicate the additional information (bonus teaching material!) as such in an ideal way.

Comment: Right, the parenthetical aside works well, but as you said my, saucers and plates is *awkward* (can never spell that word correctly), as cups and saucers is the ubiquitous notional subgrouping.

Comment: '... cups, saucers and plates (bowls are not included)' does not need to be read as sub-grouping _saucers and plates_ as this is just the traditional omission of the Oxford comma. An Oxford comma would obviously suggest three subsets more strongly than two. If you really wanted two defined subgroups, there is a strategy: 'Put cups & mugs and saucers & plates in two separate boxes.' You'd read this aloud thus: 'Put (cups and mugs), (and saucers and plates), in two separate boxes.

Comment: Yes, that would be legible.

Answer (score 1):

> *We were informed a complete set of dishes consists of these items: cups, saucers and plates (bowls are not included).*

**or**,

> *We were informed a complete set of dishes consists of these items: cups, saucers and plates, bowls are not included.*

**or**,

> *We were informed a complete set of dishes consists of these items: cups; saucers and plates; bowls are not included.*

Comment: Of the three options Little Eva gave, I would consider the first as ideal,the second and third as ambiguous or hard-to-understand. The use of semicons does not help; if anything it implies that "saucers and plates" constitute a sub-grouping, which is not substantiated by the original unpunctuated sentence.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock - I beg to differ, the *set* [of dishes] are composed of *subsets*, which in aggregate, complete the set [of dishes].

Comment: +1 for the first, which is ideal. The second is confusing, but the third a reasonable alternative.

Comment: And I agree with Brian (and 'cups and saucers' is the usual notional subgrouping); there's also a comma splice in the second.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - that's true. Ya'll have convinced me to down vote my own answer! :-) What's a 'comma splice'?

Comment: You can read Nordquist's balanced treatment [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/comspliceterm.htm). In your second example, you have to extend the definition to include [independent clause followed by list] + [independent clause] as well as [independent clause] + [independent clause]. It really doesn't work in this case; a heavier-duty stop (eg your semicolon) is needed. On the other hand, mixing super-comma semicolons and ordinary semicolons is not a good idea either.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - *super-comma semicolons*? You mean with bold type? :-)

Comment: As in: 'For breakfast, you have a choice of beans,sausages, and toast; bacon, egg, and hash browns; or ham, tomatoes, and mushrooms.' But preferably not mixed with a true semicolon: 'For breakfast, you have a choice of beans,sausages, and toast; bacon, egg, and hash browns; or ham, tomatoes, and mushrooms; bacon, egg, and hash browns is what I'm having.'

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I get it. A super-comma is used in lists that are detailed and complex, as in your first example. In the second, 'bacon, egg, and hash browns is what I'm having.' should be an indepenant sentence.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20355/discussion-between-edwin-ashworth-and-little-eva).

Answer (score 1):

We were informed [that] a complete set of dishes consists of these items: cups, saucers, and plates—bowls are not included.

OR

We were informed [that] a complete set of dishes consists of these items: cups, saucers, and plates. Bowls are not included.

The last comma is a matter of style. See any discussion of "Oxford Comma".

Comment: The first example's not bad; the second transforms the one question into two. I'm not sure that's allowed.

Comment: Nor am I sure whether that's allowed. But it said "insert punctuation where needed"; it didn't say  "punctuate this sentence". So I didn't think using two periods was specifically disallowed.

Comment: In any case, I'm so naïve. I didn't realize we were doing someone's homework. Oh well. :-)

Comment: I'm not too happy about the empty complementiser after _inform_ either, Brian. Are you right-pond?