# How do you introduce a non-quote?

Tags: commas, clauses, quotes, that

Initially, I drafted the following sentence.

*He argues we consistently make assumptions that are wrong.*

Later, because it looked like a quote, I added a comma. But, do I need a comma?

*He argues, we consistently make assumptions that are wrong.*

However, the sentence is not a quote. I am simply summarizing a seminar I attended, and I have found I am using this sentence structure often. Plus, for the sake of variety, I would like to flip this basic structure.

*We consistently make assumptions that are wrong, he argues.*

Unfortunately, I have searched both my "Chicago Manual of Style" and "The Chicago Guide to Grammar, Usage, and Punctuation" with no luck at finding any examples highlighting this condition.

For a moment, I thought CMoS Section 6.27 applied. In my example sentence, maybe *that* is implied. So, I thought I might have found my black-and-white answer. I don't need a comma. However, it seems odd to me that *we consistently make assumptions that are wrong* would be considered a restrictive relative clause. If I were to drop *he aruges*, the sentence is still complete. Plus, relative clauses are normally shorter. Lastly, Section 6.27 did not provide any direction if I were to flip the sentence.

Subsequently, I also found CMoS Section 6.42 which comes close as well. However, it deals with questions, not statements. But, its example sentences are quite close to my example.

Thus, I dove into the sections on sentence structure in "The Chicago Guide to Grammar, Usage, and Punctuation," researching subject, object, and verb. However, as I watch the clock, I have realized I need expert help. I understand there are often no black-and-white answers, but can anyone point me to the correct section related to the structure of my example? Can someone help me understand the parts of my example sentence as they relate to any particular "rule" in CMoS? Is *that* implied? Is the comma required? Is the comma only preferred? May I flip the sentence? How does it relate to the rules of a quote? Are these two independent clauses? I think there are many technical ways to approach my question, and any one answer would help me dig out of my rabbit hole.

Comment: It looks like you are talking about "reported speech"...

Comment: I think adding a comma made it look more like a quote (that is, a paraphrase-like one, without any quotation marks, that we see in news reports, etc). *That* is implied, as you suspected, making it reported speech: *He argues [that] we consistently make assumptions that are wrong.* There's nothing wrong with this.

Comment: 'He argues that we consistently make assumptions that are wrong.' If you're unhappy with the non-socially-distanced _that_'s, 'He argues that we consistently make wrong assumptions'. 'His argument is that we consistently make assumptions that are wrong' is closer in emphasis and camouflages the non-social-distancing of the  _that_'s. // I don't think 'argue' can be properly used as a reporting verb proper without 'that' (as a quotative verb, certainly). << He argues: "We consistently make assumptions that are wrong." >> but << He argues that we consistently make assumptions that are wrong. >>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help me with punctuation, please!](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222398/help-me-with-punctuation-please) It addresses << We were informed [that] ... >> rather than << He argues [that] ... >>, but the principles involved are identical, and the essentialness or otherwise of complementiser 'that' is very similar. As per Grice, include it when any hint of confusion / ambiguity would otherwise ensue.

Comment: Edwin, I think your link does relate, but it certainly focuses primarily on serial commas and a variety of other punctuation issues. However, I still thank you. I think it certainly supports "he argues" with no comma.

Comment: niamulbengali, I am happy I picked up on the implied "that." Thanks. I am an architect, so language isn't my profession. Section 6.27 certainly discusses how it is acceptable to omit "that." However, its examples do not use a clause like "he argues."

Comment: Cascabel, I have searched "reported speech," and I think you are right! However, after a bit of digging, I have only found Section 13.45. It is quite short, and ironically, refers back to Section 6.42. Section 6.42 only addresses questions and partially indicates a comma is required. I think I am piecing together the "rule," but I am surprised it is not directly addressed. And, that leads me to my next question. If "he argues" is acceptable without a comma, what rule manages how "he argues" is placed at the end of the sentence? A comma is certainly needed in that condition.

Comment: So, would everything after the implied "that" be the object of the sentence? Or, are both halves of the sentence independent clauses?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access to CMoS. But I do know what works:

> He argues that we consistently make assumptions that are wrong.

You can omit "that"; it may not be as clear, but it's not wrong:

> He argues we consistently make assumptions that are wrong.

The next example is confusing -- it looks like a comma splice between independent sentences "He argues" and "We consistently make assumptions that are wrong":

> He argues, we consistently make assumptions that are wrong.

This next one is less confusing, though it's a little unusual:

> We consistently make assumptions that are wrong, he argues.

Finally, I sometimes see thoughts treated like quotations except without quote marks -- in fiction. I think it would be too informal for nonfiction.

> We consistently make assumptions that are wrong, he thought.

> He thought, We consistently make assumptions that are wrong.